# Maximum allowable negative signal swing

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

What is meant by maximum allowable negative signal swing in the case of BJT amplifiers?  What is the formula to find the same?  What can be a practical example for the same?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you would like to draw a circuit what you mean. Without a circuit there can be no answer. There are a lot of amplifier circuits with BJTs.

Comment: `in the case of BJT amplifiers` which one? There are tons. An example schematic would be helpful.

Comment: What does the datasheet of the BJT say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output voltage swing simply means the range of values your output voltage can take. The reason it is negative in this amplifier is because in this amplifier the output voltage Vce decreases to a minimum value of 0.3V.

Comment: There's no indication that the output swing is what's being asked about, rather than the input signal swing (which is what I would interpret it to mean).